# how to read data from mysql to flink parallelly?

Tags: mysql, database, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

how to read data from mysql to flink parallelly?I want to build a sourceFunction  to continuously read data every a period of time from mysql in parallel.How can I achieve it？

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question includes two aspects:

1. reading from MySQL (or any other JDBC source) in parallel
2. reading from MySQL (or any other JDBC source) in periodic intervals

#### Reading from MySQL in parallel

In order to read from MySQL in parallel, you need to send multiple different queries. The queries must be composed in a way that the union of their results is equivalent to the expected result. For example, you can use range predicates to split queries among a numeric attribute:

```
Q1: SELECT * FROM sourceT WHERE num < 10;
Q2: SELECT * FROM sourceT WHERE num >= 10 AND num < 20;
Q3: SELECT * FROM sourceT WHERE num >= 20;
```

There are also other ways to partition a query. But in order to actually gain something, the DBMS must be able to handle multiple queries more efficiently than a single query that queries the whole table. So usually, you want to ensure that the attribute across which you partition (`num` in the example above) is indexed. Still, shooting multiple queries at a single database instance causes overhead. So, it's not trivial to find the parallelism that gives the best performance.

#### Reading from MySQL in periodic intervals

This works similar to the parallel read. Again, you need to partition your query. But now you'd like want to do this based on an attribute that describes the time of the records. So in each interval, you want to ask for the rows that were inserted since the last interval. Again, this would be done with a range predicate on the time attribute.

```
Q at T1: SELECT * FROM sourceT WHERE rowtime < T1;
Q at T2: SELECT * FROM sourceT WHERE rowtime < T2;
```

As before, this only works efficiently if the table is indexed on the `rowtime` attribute. Otherwise, you'll do a full table scan and the query will become slower and slower as more data is inserted.

#### Reading from MySQL in parallel in periodic intervals

For this you "just" have to combine both approaches and add two predicates to each query. What you essentially do is to partition the table into disjunctive parts and read them in parallel over time.

However as I pointed out before, the exact partitioning depends on your data and use case. Moreover, you need to create appropriate indexes to avoid full table scans. Please note as well, that with the approach above, you won't see any updates of rows that are modified after they were read.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer ! Also,I want to ask that  how can I split the query and distribute different queries to different source workers in flink?Thank you sooo much!

Comment: You can compute the partition of each parallel instance using the number of paralllel subtasks and the id of the current subtask. This gives you the number of partitions and which partition each subtask is responsible for. This information is available on the `RuntimeContext` that can be requested by a `RichFunction`.

Comment: Thanks sir! Also,I want to ask how to set parallelism of the sourceFunction?   When I set "StreamExecutionEnvironment.setParallelism(N)", will the parallelism of the source be N too?

Comment: Only if you implement it as a `ParallelSourceFunction`. If you extend the `SourceFunction` interface it will always have a parallelism of 1.